# Identification of a weak limit using pointwise a.e. convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

Let $X$ be a bounded domain.

We have a sequence $b_n(t) \to b(t)$ pointwise a.e. (no dependence on space), and functions $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(X))$ such that $b_n\nabla f_n \rightharpoonup g$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(X))$.

We know that $\nabla f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(X))$, and also each $b_n \in L^\infty(0,T)$ (but the bound is not uniform).

Is it possible to say that $g=b\nabla f$?

Note that $b_nf_n \to bf$ pointwise a.e.  But we don't know if $bf \in L^2(0,T;L^2)$ or not. And we don't know anything about boundedness of $b$ a priori.

Comment: How do you take the gradient of a function in $L^2$?

Comment: @PhoemueX What do you mean? We have $f_n$ and $f$ in $L^2(0,T;H^1(X))$ as written int he OP.

Comment: You wrote $L^2(0,T; L^2(X))$, not $L^2(0,T;H^1(X))$.

Comment: See the third paragraph and the second paragraph

Comment: If I understood correctly, $b_n(t)$ are not uniformly bounded in $L^\infty$. Are they uniformly bounded in $L^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$?

Comment: @gaucho A priori, no, I don't know that they are.